# How to handle per-connection metadata for a logger?

Tags: logging, connection

In a web service, we want to add a piece of metadata that can allow us to filter logs per connection so we can track what's happening from start to finish without having logs related to other connections intertwined.

So for logs that look like this:

```
Starting connection A
Starting connection B
Something happens on A
Something happens on B
```

I want to filter for entries happening on connection A only.

At the moment, we have a global logger

```js
export const logger = createLogger()
```

This works fine until the time comes to add that per-connection information.

- If we make a new logger per connection and pass it around, it ends up being passed to absolutely everything and I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
- If we add the data manually every time, then we still need to pass that data around and it also feels wrong and we might miss some places.

Is there some other pattern that can be useful in that situation?